# Not able to identify web element - span class in selenium

Tags: html, css, selenium

Is there a way to determine the type of web element? I want to determine whether a web element is.
Tried with xpath CSS classname, but it didn't work for me.

```
<span data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" class="tabLabel" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
    <span data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode" role="presentation" class="dijitNoIcon"></span>
    <span>Benefits</span>
</span>
```

I am not able to understand which one I need to take like Xpath CSS or classname.

```
WebElement Benefits = driver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.cssSelector("//div[@class='dijitTabContainer']/div[1]/div[6]//span[text()='Benefits']"));
Benefits.click();
```

or

```
WebElement Benefits = driver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//div[@class='dijitTabContainer']/div[1]/div[6]//span[text()='Benefits']")); 
Benefits.click();
```

can you help me to fix this

Comment: What do you mean by *the type of web element*? `WebElement` is `WebElement`. What did you try and what was the problem with it?

Comment: I am not able to understand which one I need to take like Xpath CSS or classname. WebElement Benefits = driver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.cssSelector("//div[@class='dijitTabContainer']/div[1]/div[6]//span[text()='Benefits']"));
Benefits.click(); WebElement Benefits = driver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//div[@class='dijitTabContainer']/div[1]/div[6]//span[text()='Benefits']"));
Benefits.click(); can you help me to fix this

Comment: `can you help me to fix this` Fix what? try to explain exactly what are you trying to achieve and what is failing